# Visual Studio Visualizer for IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, debuggervisualizer

**TL;DR**
Does anyone know how to write a Debug Visualizer for Visual Studio 2012, in C#, so I can visualize `IEnumerable<string>`, `string[]` or similar objects?

**More Info**
Visual Studio Debug Visualizer are great, and I use some popular ones ([Mole](http://www.molosoft.com/)) regularly.
However, now the time has come to roll out some custom visualizers. I started off with a simple visualizer for a string:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(My.Namespace.DebuggerSide),
                                            typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
                                            Target = typeof(string),
                                            Description = "Awesome Visualizer")]
```

the code of DebuggerSide is basically the example from the template:

```
public class DebuggerSide : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
{
    protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
    {
        if (windowService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("windowService");
        if (objectProvider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("objectProvider");


        var data = (string)objectProvider.GetObject();

        using (var displayForm = new VisualizerForm(data))
        {
            windowService.ShowDialog(displayForm);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tests the visualizer by hosting it outside of the debugger.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectToVisualize">The object to display in the visualizer.</param>
    public static void TestShowVisualizer(object objectToVisualize)
    {
        VisualizerDevelopmentHost visualizerHost = new VisualizerDevelopmentHost(objectToVisualize, typeof(DebuggerSide));
        visualizerHost.ShowVisualizer();
    }
}
```

`VisualizerForm` is the custom form with extra controls etc...
when I build the project and put the dll in the `My Documents/Visual Studio 11/Visualizers` folder, and restart visual studio, I can indeed see the debugger appearing under the looking glass icon when a breakpoint is hit for a string object. Woohoo! So far so good.

Now I would like to, instead of visualizing `string`, visualize `string[]` or `IEnumerable<string>` or a similar object. However when I change the assembly attribute to `IEnumerable<string>`, this is not working, there is not even a looking glass icon displayed on the IEnumerable objects.

**UPDATE**
I can get it to work by changing the TargetType to `List<>` and then checking if I can cast to `List<string>`. However, this means I have to cast all my objects I want to debug to `List` and can't use `IEnumerable<>` or string[]

Comment: +1 for Mole. I was trying to write a visualizer for collections and I see it already has it. Going to try Mole now. **Update:** Mole is no longer being sold. Back to writing a visualizer.

Comment: Give this a shot, works for all objects: https://github.com/amithegde/LpDump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualizers are documented as

> Support for generic types is limited. You can write a visualizer for a target that is a generic type only if the generic type is an open type.

Which means you cannot write a visualizer that uses a closed constructed type like `IEnumerable<string>`.

Have you tried setting the target type to `IEnumerable<>` then checking to see if the elements are of type `string`?

Comment: thanks, I'm indeed using an approach where I check the contents of the object.

Answer (score 1):

See the 'Objects that can have debugger visualizers' section here:
https://rapiddevbookcode.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EnumerableDebugVisualizer

My Enumerable Debugger Visualizer will work with an IEnumerable if the underlying concrete type registered with it, you could look at the registration code to get yours working.